# Sencha application cost too much ram

Tags: android, extjs

I'm currently develop some android applications using sencha.
The problem is my apps using a lot of ram when running, when i press home button and see in Settings, it usually cost about 150mb in Cached Processes and increase time by time. So it cause the app is crashed a lot and almost restart whenever press the app's icon in menu. 
Is there anyway for me to decrease usage Ram  or prevent app automatically exit or crashed, please give me your idea.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use custom components? I don't know if you are aware, but in Sencha apps you should always remember to cleanup in destroy method. If you have custom components without proper cleanup method then you have your answer. Also any global variables may cause issue. Use for example jslint to validate your JS code, maybe it will point something out.

Comment: Hi Lolo, thanks for your answer. 
I will follow as your advise.